# Groovy traits doesn't have generated default getters and setters as documented

Tags: java, groovy, traits

According to documentation of Groovy the behavior of getters and setters generating should be similar to common classes. But I have an issue ... common Groovy classes do have these getters and setters generated in my code but I need to write explicit setters and getters or my code does not compile.

```
@MappedSuperclass
trait Versioned {
    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    Long version
}
```

When another grrovy class implemented the trait the message was:

"error: PersistentCommand is not abstract and does not override abstract method setVersion(Long) in Versioned"

My Groovy is older (2.4.15) but the rest is now up to date IntelliJ Idea 2020.2.3, Gradle 6.7. By the way I have checked traits documentation of exact Groovy version I use.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: you have to provide exact syntax that does not work for you. because this one works fine: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_properties

Comment: I see such warnings in Eclipse 2020-06 and groovy-eclipse feature, but the code compiles fine

Comment: @daggett I slightly updated it but it is exact syntax. I don't think those anotations that were not provided are relevant

Comment: And I have another problem here ... Similar case but the trait field is generic. It dosn't compile even with explicitly written getter and setter because of missing geter and setter. Even though IntelliJ can see it. Just the groovy compiler. I think it is the old version of groovy .... I will try to update it

Answer (score 1):

So after some experimenting I can confirm my suspect. The problem was groovy version that was too old and probably caused some issues. With groovy 2.5.13 it behaves as expected

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer. i just want to show that your code works.

```
@Grab(group='javax.persistence', module='javax.persistence-api', version='2.2')
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass
import javax.persistence.Version
import javax.persistence.Column

@MappedSuperclass
trait Versioned {
    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    Long version
}

@groovy.transform.ToString
class V implements Versioned{
    String name
}

def v=new V(version:123,name:"world")
```